# getting error on pivot for syntax when converting rows as column

Tags: sql-server

i am using sql server and wants my table rows as columns when i convert with this query its give me error on for keyword that

> Incorrect syntax near '1'.
>   this is my query

```
select strvalue,1,2
from
(select  strvalue,nSectionAttributeId,

(row_number()  over (partition by nSectionAttributeId  order by nsectionattributeid ) ) as colum
 from tblAttributeData
 )temp

 pivot
 (
 max(nSectionAttributeId)
 for colum in (1,2)
 )PIV
```

Comment: Put the values inside square brackets `([1], [2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select strvalue,1,2
from
(select  strvalue,nSectionAttributeId,

(row_number()  over (partition by nSectionAttributeId  order by nsectionattributeid ) ) as colum
 from tblAttributeData
 )temp

 pivot
 (
 max(nSectionAttributeId)
 for colum in ([1],[2])
 )PIV
```

Comment: that is very kind of you

Comment: hi is there is a way in my pivot rows columns i only display one rows because now its make two columns with 1 and 2 i wants only one columns like data and where goes 1 and 2